# Cassandra data modeling with multi-column filter

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra table `stokes` which has 4 columns `( item(text) ,market ( text ) , location( text ) , time ( timestamp ) , value( int) )`  item is a partition key and market , location and time is a clustering key in same order .

```
item | market | location | time | value
 x   |  m1    | l1       | t1   | v1
 x   |  m1    | l2       | t2   | v2
 x   |  m1    | l3       | t3   | v3
 y   |  m1    | l1       | t4   | v4
 y   |  m1    | l2       | t5   | v5
 y   |  m1    | l3       | t6   | v6
```

Application has require to query to Cassandra table in two scenario

1. For given item , market and location fetch the record by querying to  stock table .
   for example item x, market l1 and location l1 below record will be fetched

```
 x   |  m1    | l1       | t1   | v1
```

2. For given item , market and all location after input time fetch the record by querying to  stock table . For example item x , market m1 , all location after t1 time below records will be fetched

   ```
    x   |  m1    | l2       | t2   | v2
    x   |  m1    | l3       | t3   | v3
   ```

I understand in Cassandra application requirement and conceptual modeling comes first in deformalizing the data modeling . How I cam model data to meet both of my application requirement .

For my second requirement I am not able to query like

```
select <columns> from <table> where item =x and market= m1 and time > t2; // wrong as location missing
```

Skipping location is not allowed and locations could be multiple . How to model or query to meet both requirement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first app query, the partition key is `item` and both `market` and `location` are clustering columns:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    item text,
    market text,
    location text,
    time timestamp,
    value int,
    PRIMARY KEY (item, market, location)
)
```

For the second app query, it looks similar to the `items` table except the data is organised by `market` and `time`:

```
CREATE TABLE locations_by_item (
    item text,
    market text,
    location text,
    time timestamp,
    value int,
    PRIMARY KEY (item, market, time)
)
```

When you retrieve data from this table with:

```
SELECT * FROM locations_by_item
  WHERE item = ?
  AND market = ?
  AND time > ?
```

it will return rows of `location` + `value`. Cheers!

Comment: By this data model design, backed services has burden of updating 2 different tables of similar data . It’s a performance issue for system . Can we do something with one table .

Comment: It's actually the opposite because writes are very fast and very cheap in Cassandra. Reads are expensive so you have to design multiple tables to optimise the reads and make them really fast. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick , would you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71255937/cassandra-map-write-lock-multithreading